# Need to join MySql query to 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT products.acctnum,products.subacctnum,NOW(),
    items.amount,items.id,items.invoice_id,items.product_id,
    items.po_id, invoices.customer_id, purchaseorders.vendor_id FROM items
    INNER JOIN (products, invoices, purchaseorders)
            ON (items.product_id=products.product_id AND items.invoice_id=invoices.id
    AND items.po_id=purchaseorders.id)
```

This returns nothing... however..

```
SELECT products.acctnum,products.subacctnum,NOW(),
    items.amount,items.id,items.invoice_id,items.product_id,
    items.po_id, purchaseorders.vendor_id FROM items
    INNER JOIN (products, purchaseorders)
            ON (products.product_id=items.product_id AND purchaseorders.id=items.po_id)
```

Works...

```
SELECT products.acctnum,products.subacctnum,NOW(),
    items.amount,items.id,items.invoice_id,items.product_id,
    items.po_id, invoices.customer_id FROM items
    INNER JOIN (products, invoices)
            ON (products.product_id=items.product_id AND invoices.id=items.invoice_id)
```

Works...

Works for the rows I need in the result but when I join the 3rd table it doesn't work.  LEFT JOIN displayed all the columns I needed but some rows were NULL.

Comment: Apparently, items have either a purchase order or an invoice, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the `join` clause you want looks more like this:

```
FROM items LEFT JOIN
     invoices
     ON invoices.id = items.invoice_id LEFT JOIN
     purchaseorders
     ON purchaseorders.id = items.po_id LEFT JOIN
     products
     ON products.product_id = items.product_id
```

I'm not sure which fields are not valid when you select them, but you can probably fix such issues by using `coalesce()` with appropriate fields from `invoices` and `purchaseorders`.